# What's the point of chr(128) .. chr(255) in Python?

Tags: python, ascii

Edit: I'm talking about behavior in Python 2.7.

The `chr` function converts integers between 0 and 127 into the ASCII characters. E.g.

```
>>> chr(65)
'A'
```

I get how this is useful in certain situations and I understand why it covers 0..127, the 7-bit ASCII range.

The function also takes arguments from 128..255. For these numbers, it simply returns the hexadecimal representation of the argument. In this range, different bytes mean different things depending on which part of the [ISO-8859](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859#The_Parts_of_ISO.2FIEC_8859) standard is used.

I'd understand if `chr` took another argument, e.g.

```
>>> chr(228, encoding='iso-8859-1') # hypothetical
'ä'
```

However, there is no such option:

```
chr(i) -> character

Return a string of one character with ordinal i; 0 <= i < 256.
```

My questions is: What is the point of raising `ValueError` for `i > 255` instead of `i > 127`? All the function does for `128 <= i < 256` is return hex values?

Comment: What makes you say it returns hex values. Compare `print(str(c))` with `print(repr(c))`.

Comment: `chr(128)` => '\x80', `chr(129)` => '\x81', etc.

Comment: What you are seeing is the *representation* of the given string, rather than would would be see on terminal if the character was printed.

Comment: You also have to remember that `str` in python 2.x is also used as a byte array. In such situations a way to create string values for all the possible values a byte can take is required.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In Python 2.x, a `str` is a sequence of bytes, so `chr()` returns a string of one byte and accepts values in the range 0-255, as this is the range that can be represented by a byte. When you print the `repr()` of a string with a byte in the range 128-255, the character is printed in escape format because there is no standard way to represent such characters (ASCII defines only 0-127). You can convert it to Unicode using `unicode()` however, and specify the source encoding:

```
unicode(chr(200), encoding="latin1")
```

In Python 3.x, `str` is a sequence of Unicode characters and `chr()` takes a much larger range. Bytes are handled by the `bytes` type.

Answer (score 0):

I see what you're saying but it isn't correct. In Python 3.4 `chr` is documented as:

> Return the string representing a character whose Unicode codepoint is the integer i.

And here are some examples:

```
>>> chr(15000)
'㪘'
>>> chr(5000)
'ᎈ'
```

In Python 2.x it was:

> Return a string of one character whose ASCII code is the integer i.

The function `chr` has been around for a long time in Python and I think the understanding of various encodings only developed in recent releases. In that sense it makes sense to support the basic ASCII table and return hex values for the extended ASCII set within the 128 - 255 range.

Even [within Unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0000.pdf) the ASCII set is only defined as 128 characters, not 256, so there isn't (wasn't) a standard and accepted way of letting `ord()` return an answer for those input values.

Comment: For Python 2.7, it *is* correct. I've edited the question to make that clear.

Comment: "Even within Unicode the ASCII set is only defined as 128 characters, not 256". ASCII only has 128 characters so why would Unicode define it with 256?

Comment: @lmichelbacher: aren't you answering your original question here? If ASCII only has 128 characters then Unicode follows that, and as such, there is no "ASCII answer" for the 128 - 256 range. I included that to show that both back then and now, the 128 - 256 range has no fixed set of characters within ASCII. I hope this helps.

Comment: 'there is no "ASCII answer" for the 128 - 256 range'. Exactly. That's why I was wondering why `chr` returns anything at all for this range. There's no answer for the 256+ range either and *that* range raises an error.

Answer (score 0):

Note that python 2 string handling is broken. It's one of the reasons I recommend switching to python 3.

In python 2, the string type was designed to represent both text and binary strings. So, chr() is used to convert an integer to a byte. It's not really related to text, or ASCII, or ISO-8859-1. It's a binary stream of bytes:

```
 binary_command = chr(100) + chr(200) + chr(10)
 device.write(binary_command)
 etc()
```

In python 2.7, the bytes() type was added for forward compatibility with python 3 and it maps to str().